# Percentage of feature area covered by features of other layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover under MacOS 10.13 environment. I've got two polygon layers `A` and `B` with multiple features in each. I want to calculate, for each feature in layer `A`, the percentage of its area that is actually covered by any feature of layer `B`. I have built in the field calculator of layer `A` the following code, that seems to work in some cases, but definitely doesn't in others

```
(area(intersection($geometry, collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('B', $geometry)))))*100/area($geometry)
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see three cases when this does not work:

1. If a feature is not covered at all (result = NULL) (which is actually correct)
2. If covering features of B do overlap each other
3. If the intersection of both layers is of type `GeometryCollection`

To cover both cases, you can use this expression:

```
coalesce((area(buffer(intersection($geometry, buffer(collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('b', $geometry)),0)),0)))*100/area($geometry),0)
```

Explanation:

- for case 1) `coalesce()` will cover the NULL case and insert 0 if no
  result is returned by the actual expression.
- for case 2) `buffer(...,0)` will dissolve the overlapping parts of the multipolygon by a buffer of 0 (workaround since there is no actual `dissolve()` function) so will prevent from causing an error in the calculation
- for case 3) just add another buffer to turn the `GeometryCollection` (result of `intersection()`) into a `MultiPolygon`

Example:

[image]

Comment: Beautifully solved and explained.

Comment: Unfortunately, @MrXsquared, there are 30 cases out of 402 in which it doesn't work. For example, this feature (in red) do overlap with 3 features of the `B` layer [link] (https://cloud.mail.ru/public/yKQS/Xe9aPNUgZ). See the attributes table [link] (https://cloud.mail.ru/public/EKR1/k5AF2xe2g) where the 3 features are listed using this code `array_to_string(overlay_intersects('B', SITE_CODE))`, but the calculated overlapping area is 0.

Comment: Huhm, cant really tell.. are the geometries valid? Is it possible for you to share that specific data so we can try and test? You could also try to do the calculation steps without expressions but step by step using processing tools, maybe you will then find the cause.

Comment: I've prepared two sample layers where the issue arises (https://cloud.mail.ru/public/BXw6/eqeoHhsnT). It seems to have to do with multipolygons and geometries with holes. Perhaps other "peculiar" geometries act that way too.

Comment: Was the same issue as I covered with case 2: The resulting geometry of `intersection()` is of type `GeometryCollection`, you can turn it into a `MultiPolygon` by just adding another buffer and it should work: `coalesce((area(buffer(intersection($geometry, buffer(collect_geometries(overlay_intersects('b', $geometry)),0)),0)))*100/area($geometry),0)`

Comment: Brilliant! Now it works smoothly. Would you mind ammending the answer above, please?