# Calculating overlapping areas using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, overlapping-features, calculate-geometry

I am new to QGIS.

I have a grid layer as layer one.
Polygon’s layer with many polygons as layer two.

I **need** to calculate the ratio of an overlapping area in one square of the grid where two polygons overlapped in.

The solution needs to be applicable at a larger scale, if possible. In the actual case, I‘m working on, there are millions of grid squares, and thousands of polygons.

In this case, shown in the figure below, I have 1 square and 2 partially overlapping polygons as the figure down. Note that the polygons both partially overlap with each other and partially overlap with the square.
OBS: See the table

I want to create a table for example with four rows and three columns:
as in the table below

[image]

Note that it’s not important that the table has exactly this structure. However, this is the information I would like to get out of the exercise.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397101/88814 and probably this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392861/88814